# lsblk does not indicate if partition is a swap disk on Arch 2020.02.01

Tags: arch-linux, partition, swap

I'm trying to install Arch Linux on VMware workstation following [Installing Arch Linux on VMware Workstation](https://chaseafterstart.github.io/).

I have created four partitions with cfdisk `/dev/sda` including a swap disk on `/dev/sda2`.

I ran:

```
mkswap /dev/sda2
```

Yet when I run `lsblk` I just see:

```
|-sda2  8:1  0  1G  part
```

`[SWAP]` is missing. What did I miss? Is this important?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I forgot to run:

```
swapon /dev/sda2
```